# Rspec shared setting variables for many test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Tests are set by Rspec + factory girl, and I have around 20 Rspec test files, all of them share some of the required setting variables. Eg:

```
   let!(:event) { create(:event) }
   let!(:user) { create(:user) }
   let!(:user) { create(:ticket) }
```

I don't want to copy paste these variables assignment for each test file, Is there a cleaner way to populate the vars? Thanks in advance.

Comment: put them in a before block in your tests.  So before do let!(:event) { create(:event) }
   let!(:user) { create(:user) }
   let!(:user) { create(:ticket) }

Answer (score 1):

If yo're using let, you don't need to repeat them. It will persist through the current describe/context block.

eg the following should all pass:

```
describe 'some stuff' do

   let!(:event) { create(:event) }

   it 'should get an event' do  
      expect(event).to_not be_nil
   end 

   describe 'indented stuff' do

     let!(:user) { create(:user) }

     it 'should still get an event' do  
        expect(event).to_not be_nil
     end

     it 'should get a user' do  
        expect(user).to_not be_nil
     end

   end
end
```

To share setup amongst more than one file, define a method in rails_helper/spec_helper:

```
module CommonSetup 
  def setup_vars
    let!(:event) { create(:event) }
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }
    let!(:user) { create(:ticket) }
  end
end
...
...
Rspec.configure do |c|
...
  c.extend CommonSetup 
...
end
```

And then in your spec just call setup_vars in your spec

Comment: Hmmm.. Thanks for the answer, but my question is shared variables for multiple test files. Your answer above seems to work for one test file.?

Comment: Yeah, it will. Because I answered before you edited your question to say that it was multiple files :P

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I got the following after following the edit:
undefined method `let!' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000101f04ec8>